# Avoid menu toggle to close when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I'm using a `.fadeToggle` menu on my site.

I'm having some buttons that are showing a different div when clicking on them.

Everything's correct and you can be navigating on it but I want to avoid user to be clicking on the same button and close the info (it makes the screen be completely blank).

If I'm using the `e.stopPropagation()` I'm not able to navigate through it.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
 </div><div id="toggleContainer2">
    <p><p>This is not an advertising platform, all selected agencies are more or less a subjective choice. The author reserves the right not to be responsible for the topicality, correctness, completeness or quality of the information provided. Liability claims regarding damage caused by the use of any information provided, including any kind of information which is incomplete or incorrect, will therefore be rejected. </p>
<p>All offers are not-binding and without obligation. Parts of the pages or the complete publication including all offers and information might be extended, changed or partly or completely deleted by the author without separate announcement.</p></p>
  </div>
```

...

```
 <a class="btn" id="trigger2">Disclaimer</a>
```

**JS:**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // toggle advanced search
  $("#toggleContainer2").hide();
  $("#trigger2").click(function() {
    $("#toggleContainer2").fadeToggle(1500);
    $("#toggleContainer").hide();
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Oscar. Welcome to StackOverflow!. Can you edit your question and add your HTML ?

Comment: Hello @Ahmad! Thanks a lot. You can check it now!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've been re-read your post, your problem is you didn't understand how .fadeToggle works, because what you describe is exactly what it is intented for.

What you need is to read that : [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) because it's the function that you need.

**Older answer**
What you need is to change the way you're tracking the target of the event.

Let say your dropdown as the class .dd and your button class is .menu_b, you will got something like this

```
$('body').on('click','.menu_b',function(e){
  if($(e.target).hasClass('menu_b')) {
    $('.dd').fadeToggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Now I need to figure something to make the .dd2 be hided when .dd is visible and vice versa.

Comment: you can do that simply by giving a common class to all your "dd", for exemple, .my_dd. And then you do a $('.my_dd').hide() before anything else when you click on one of them. (Btw, if the main answer was satisfying, don't forget to upvote it ;) much apreciate)